# how to make overlay like youtube

Tags: html, css

I am having a simple web page with a `navigation` bar. When is toggle my navigation bar I want the rest of area in my page to be overlay live Youtube(A sample image is attached below). But after trying 100 time the result is attached below(A sample image is attached below).The problem is it's not `overlaying` the element which has defined `color` attribute.

[image][image]

My css code to achieve overlay:

```
.overlay{
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed !fixed;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
        z-index:0;
        cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Comment: This is not valid css : `position: fixed !fixed;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example just plays with `visibility` and `opacity` of overlay wrapper.

```js
$("#click").on("click", function(){
    $(".orientation-check-wrapper").toggleClass('show-overlay');
});
```

```css
.orientation-check-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    opacity:0;
    transition: .4s all;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.orientation-check-text {
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 390px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #3493c1;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.show-overlay{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#click{
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="click" />

<div class="orientation-check-wrapper">
     <div class="orientation-check-text">This application is best supported on resolutions above 800px</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You need to add an higher `z-index` and a grey background overlay.

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").show();
});
```

```css
    .overlay {
     background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.40);
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 99999;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="overlay">
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea velit provident sint aliquid eos omnis aperiam officia architecto error incidunt nemo obcaecati adipisci doloremque dicta neque placeat natus beatae cupiditate minima ipsam quaerat explicabo non reiciendis qui sit.</div>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As side note, the `opacity` css rule is now widely available, in case of usage of rgb. It can be useful when playing with js.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated a post with some code which may probably very helpful to simulate YouTube like overlay.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".overlay, .close").hide();
  $("#btnClickme").bind("click", function() {
    $(".overlay, .close").fadeIn();
    $(".wrapper-btn").fadeOut();
  });
  $(".btnClose").bind("click", function() {
    $(".overlay, .close").fadeOut();
    $(".close").unbind("click");
    $(".wrapper-btn").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 12px;
}

.close a {
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:13px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper-row {
  float: left;
}

.overlay {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overlay-wrapper'>
  <div class="wrapper-row">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-row wrapper-btn">
    <input type="button" id="btnClickme" name="btnClickme" value="click here" />
  </div>
  <div class="close">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnClose">
    (close)
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the possibility of usage of **css filters** in this case, as a side technique.

They are now widely available into many browsers, we can with them do pretty nice stuffs, without adding an overlay.

Here on this simple example, the blur filter is used. The filter is added by javascript alone. This way, there is no need to modify the html or the css. It can be useful.

I took the html from the top answer, which is the good regular way to do this.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].setAttribute("onclick","this.style.filter='blur(2px)'")
```

```html
<div class="overlay">Some text
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea velit provident sint aliquid eos omnis aperiam officia architecto error incidunt nemo obcaecati adipisci doloremque dicta neque placeat natus beatae cupiditate minima ipsam quaerat explicabo non reiciendis qui sit.</div>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

The list of css filters:

```
filter: blur(5px);
filter: brightness(0.4);
filter: contrast(200%);
filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 20px blue);
filter: grayscale(50%);
filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
filter: invert(75%);
filter: opacity(25%);
filter: saturate(30%);
filter: sepia(60%);
```

Further infos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a structure like this

```
<aside class="sidebar">
   <!-- Stuff-->
</aside>
<section class="content">
    <!-- More stuff -->
</section>
```

and an `open` class is added to `sidebar` when the bar is opened, you can use the adjacent sibling combinator to get the overlay

```
.sidebar.open + .content:before {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed !fixed;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    z-index:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```